# Excel VBA copy cell to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet Stock:

| Item | quantity | add/remove |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Socks | 8 |  |
| Hats | 4 | 1 |

I then have 2 buttons one for add and one for remove.
I then have a log sheet where every time i press either button it prints to a log file.

```
  Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Now()
  Sheets("Log").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Environ("UserName")
  Sheets("Log").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Stock added/Removed"
```

Right now im an going through each with :

```
Range("b2").Value = Range("b2") + Range("c2")
Range("b3").Value = Range("b3") + Range("c3")
```

Is there a smarter way to add? because not all cells have things to add.
Is there a way to the item name amount added from that line???

Comment: *im an going through each* - in that case use a loop  `Dim cel: For Each cel In Range("B2:B3"): cel.Value2 = cel + cel.Offset(, 1): Next`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend consolidating it into one button.

- The decision to add or remove is based on the positivity or negativity of column C.
- Add an item column in the log sheet.
- If necessary, column C can be cleared by code on the stock sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Update()
    Dim rData As Range, arrData
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sNote As String
    Set rData = Sheets("stock").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rData.Value
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 3)) > 0 And VBA.IsNumeric(arrData(i, 3)) Then
            arrData(i, 2) = arrData(i, 2) + arrData(i, 3)
            If Val(arrData(i, 3)) > 0 Then
                sNote = "Stock Added"
            Else
                sNote = "Stock Removed"
            End If
            ' Clear column C
            ' arrData(i, 3) = ""
            Sheets("log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 4).Value _
                = Array(Now(), Environ("UserName"), sNote, arrData(i, 1))
        End If
    Next
    rData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

[image]

Certainly, you can keep your current logic as is. You have the option to change just one code line to accommodate another button (Remove).

```
arrData(i, 2) = arrData(i, 2) - arrData(i, 3)
```

Comment: For an ActiveX commandbutton, call it in click event. `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Update
End Sub`.  For a Form commandbutton (or a shape), `Assign macro` to the control. [Assign a macro to a Form or a Control button](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283#:~:text=Add%20a%20button%20(Form%20control),-Follow%20these%20steps&text=tab%2C%20click%20Button%20.-,Click%20the%20worksheet%20location%20where%20you%20want%20the%20upper%2Dleft,the%20button%20and%20click%20OK.?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Is there a way to get around it breaking most of my formulas, basically only 7 and 14 are number values, rest are Formulas, and all these are changed into values?

Comment: Are you talk about `log` sheet or `stock` sheet?